# Reach a Javascript array element with a HTML option value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select

I have a select with different options and i need to reach the array's element depending on the select choice.

**HTML**

```
<select id="liste">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option> 
    <option value="1">Value 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Value 2</option> 
</select>
```

My array is like :
t_data = [5, 3, 4]

**Javascript**

```
var data = t_data[document.getElementById('liste').value]
// I also tried something like this 
var data = t_data[parseInt(document.getElementById('liste').value)]
```

But I can't get the value in the array ...

And obviously it works well when i put :

```
var data = t_data[0]
```

Must be stupid but i'm not a html/js programmer and i'm breaking down currently ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get your results .

```js
t_data = [5, 3, 4];
document.getElementById('liste').addEventListener('change', function() {
  // this will display you selected value from array in p tag
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = t_data[this.value];
  // console.log(t_data[this.value]);
});
```

```html
  <select id="liste">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option> 
    <option value="1">Value 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Value 2</option> 
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method selectedIndex.

Example:

```js
let liste = document.querySelector('#liste')

let t_data = [5, 3, 4]

let data = t_data[liste.selectedIndex])
```

```html
<select id="liste">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option> 
    <option value="1">Value 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Value 2</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code snippet below – every time you change the value of the `select` element, `t_data[liste.value]` is sent to the console.

```js
t_data = [5, 3, 4];

var liste = document.getElementById('liste');
liste.addEventListener('change', logData);

function logData() {
  var data = t_data[liste.value];
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<select id="liste">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option> 
    <option value="1">Value 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Value 2</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are doing wrong is using "value" in place of "selectedIndex".
just replace that and tada.. your code works fine.

```js
var arr = [23,24,25,26,27];
var opt = document.getElementById('liste');
var data;
opt.addEventListener('change', function(){
   data = arr[opt.selectedIndex];
   console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<select id="liste">
  <option vlaue="0">value 0</option>
  <option vlaue="1">value 1</option>
  <option vlaue="2">value 2</option>
  <option vlaue="3">value 3</option>
 </select>
```